# Assert simple conditions in Javascript without using eval

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm trying to build a Javascript program that can interpret simple conditions :

```
let condition = '5 + 6 > 10';
if( assert(condition) ){
  //... do something
} else {
  // ... do other thing
}
```

A simple but unsecure way to implement `assert` is to simply use `eval`. It works, but opens a security hole. How could I work around this ?

I need support for addition and substraction, string and numbers comparisons, and parenthesis management.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK sorry. It's been a long time I've not posted here, so I have lost my reflex. I have rephrased my question, does it look OK now ?

Comment: :-) Nicely reworded. I'm fairly sure this ground has been thoroughly covered. [This search](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+evaluate+equation+without+eval) turns up a fair bit. Happy coding!

Comment: Also worth perusing https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/ to understand eval() within the browser, server, and javascript framework...

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- you can write a tokenizer and parser for your expressions by hand. For a simple grammar like this, this isn't complicated and is actually a very good exercise in programming. Look up "shunting yard algorithm" or "recursive descent parser".
- alternatively, you can use a parser generator like [peg](https://pegjs.org) or [nearley](https://nearley.js.org/). With a generator, you write your grammar in their specific language and let the generator create a parsing function for you. Check out their examples: https://pegjs.org/online , https://github.com/kach/nearley/tree/master/examples/calculator
- finally, you can use a full-blown Javascript parser like [esprima](https://esprima.org/) or [acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn). This way you'll get a complete javascript AST, which you can walk and perform calculations as you go. This method is far more complicated that the others, but gives you the full power of javascript in your expressions, e.g. functions, regexes etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the interpreter supports toString() on functions, you can do this for example:

```
function test (f) {
  let source = f.toString().replace(/^\(\) => /,'');
  if (f()) {
    console.log(source+" succeeded");
  } else {
    console.log(source+" failed");
  }
}
let condition = () => 5 + 6 > 10;
test(condition)
test(() => 5 + 4 > 10)
```